# "." in URL's creating error on Heroku Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a simple web app that allows users to create items. I have a view for a 'user profile', but if a user enters a period into their username, it tries to add a period into the URL and then tosses an error when you try to load the profile. For instance...

username: McClure creates users/McClure

but

username: .McClure creates an error...

Anytime a period's in there it errors out. What should I to do prevent periods in the input?

Answer (score 0):

Many characters can cause errors in your url.

If you have a simple user model, the standard routes are `/users/1`, `/users/2`, etc. Now, instead of the numbers, you can use friendly ids, such as the user's name - but these have to be made URL friendly, "slugged". A slug is the conversion of the attribute you are using as friendly id to be URL ready.

You can of course create your own slugs, but there is a very easy way to do it: use the gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) with this [quickstart guide](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart). And here is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid). This gem uses slugs and generates them for you - it can even save a history of slugs for your model when the slugs change, among many other nice features.

With it, you can do something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
end
```

Then, your usernames will be used in the url in a way that is URL friendly *and* human readable. The best part is: You can leave your standard routes and user names as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Uue a Regular Expression validation like `/\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\Z/` in your model (this one only allows letters and numbers for usernames):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\Z/
  ...
end
```

Or, in Rails 4:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :username, format: { with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\Z/ }
  ...
end
```

Comment: you should use the latter format for rails 3.2 as well; the former one is deprecated